# Facebook Comment Box Callback on Load?

Tags: javascript, facebook, callback, dom-events, facebook-comments

I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for in the docs, and I'm using [one of these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) on a site, but I need to update a previously assigned variable in my JS once the comment box loads completely. Where or how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that I can think of that **might** do the trick is to subscribe to the [xfbml.render event](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

It's done like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function(response) {
  // do what ever
});
```

The documentation says:

> fired when a call to FB.XFBML.parse() completes.

So I'm not sure if it will work with existing xfbml/html5 code in the dom that is then being rendered when the *FB.init* kicks in.
If it does not, you may want to call *FB.XFBML.parse* manually instead.

Hope this helps.